# Apache2 configtest failed after installing phpmyadmin

Tags: apache, phpmyadmin, apache2

Hello I was trying to install phpmyadmin then I stuck with apache2 restarting...
When I was trying to fix it I did following stuff:

```
sudo apt-get remove apache2
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get install apache2
```

Then:

```
sudo nano /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
```

I added at the end:

```
Include /etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf
```

And restart

```
/etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

And it still doesn't work so I decide to install two following packages:

```
apt-get install libapache2-mod-php5
apt-get install php5.6 libapache2-mod-php5.6
```

And have following output when restarting:

```
 * Restarting Apache httpd web server apache2                                    [fail] 
 * The apache2 configtest failed.
Output of config test was:
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
Action 'configtest' failed.
The Apache error log may have more information.
```

The log file:

```
cat /var/log/apache2/access.log

127.0.0.1 - - [11/Jan/2017:19:17:01 +0100] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 3595 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 ($
127.0.0.1 - - [11/Jan/2017:19:17:01 +0100] "GET /icons/ubuntu-logo.png HTTP/1.1" 404 51$
127.0.0.1 - - [11/Jan/2017:19:17:01 +0100] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 500 "http://$
127.0.0.1 - - [11/Jan/2017:19:17:06 +0100] "GET /phpmyadmin HTTP/1.1" 404 499 "-" "Mozi$
127.0.0.1 - - [11/Jan/2017:19:17:56 +0100] "GET /phpmyadmin/setup/index.php HTTP/1.1" 4$
127.0.0.1 - - [11/Jan/2017:19:20:27 +0100] "GET /phpmyadmin HTTP/1.1" 404 500 "-" "Mozi$
```

The output of error log:

```
[Wed Jan 11 18:58:27.464400 2017] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 1174] AH00163: Apache/2.4.23 (Ubuntu) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Wed Jan 11 18:58:27.464420 2017] [core:notice] [pid 1174] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Wed Jan 11 19:19:27.443455 2017] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 1174] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Wed Jan 11 19:20:18.120230 2017] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 4527] AH00163: Apache/2.4.23 (Ubuntu) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Wed Jan 11 19:20:18.120268 2017] [core:notice] [pid 4527] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Wed Jan 11 19:21:19.771711 2017] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 4527] AH00171: Graceful restart requested, doing restart
AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.1.1. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
[Wed Jan 11 19:21:19.787009 2017] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 4527] AH00163: Apache/2.4.23 (Ubuntu) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Wed Jan 11 19:21:19.787018 2017] [core:notice] [pid 4527] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Wed Jan 11 19:21:20.670808 2017] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 4527] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
```

I am working on elementaryOS. Anyone know what to do in this case ?

Comment: Check the error log instead of the access log. Also try `apachectl configtest`.

Comment: @aynber apachectl configtest gives the same output as restart of the service.

Answer (score 0):

1. Check how many php you have installed and which one is required/enabled in your apache by locating directory : ***ls /etc/apache2/mods-enabled***
2. Disable php module which is not required.In my case it was php5(I have to use php7.1 instead of php5), so type : ***a2dismod php5***
3. Then restart your apache server : ***/etc/init.d/apache2 restart***